# How to check if my battery is OK?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery-life, charging

I use my phone mainly for wifi use and I know it is a battery hog. However, what I would like to know is how much time it takes for the battery to charge. I guess it is supposed to take like 4 mins to charge 1%.

I plugged in my phone at 11% battery at 1.00 am and at 7.00 am it was still charging at 65%. What seems to be the issue here ?

**Update 1:**
Going by a comment on [the post here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/257952-s3-charging-time.html), it is because of the sequence in which I connect the phone to the charger. The comment goes as follows:

> Hi I think I found the problem as to why mine was charging slow.  Make
>   sure the USB end is unplugged from the charger BEFORE plugging the
>   phone end. After plugging into the phone, plug the USB to the charger
>   while the charger is into the wall. Not sure why but the sequence is
>   Important and affects charging rate big time.
>
> Alex

This is in the manual, too. Unsure as to what the internal mechanics of the charging are.

Comment: Does your phone have LTE capability?  Do you live in an area with LTE service?

Comment: @Compro01 Yes, we do have 2G and 3G services

Comment: An issue I've had with my S3 (model I747m) is random absurd battery drain when in LTE service.  It'll go from a full charge to under 30% within 3-4 hours.  The drain tends to stop after a reboot.  I'm wondering if this drain effect may be happening when you're trying to charge and slowing the charging to a crawl.

Comment: Oh, no. I mean I am not using the LTE services. I am charging on flight mode cause it charges faster =) @Compro01

Answer (score 0):

I think what matters most is the amperage of your charger. If you are plugging your phone into a computer then it is limited to 500mA. A charger for the S3 will typically provide 1A to 2A I believe.

One more thing which may be going wrong is battery hogging applications. If you switch your phone off and then charge, by how much does your charging time lessen down?

Answer (score 0):

What Aditya Somani say is correct. The amount of amperage your charger has will determine the charge speed. However, turning off things like WiFi, LTE and probably even the whole phone will make the charge go faster.

For the wire-in-phone first thing, I believe that is a myth. I've heard it for computers and mobiles alike, but never found a reason to exactly why. My education in electronics might be vague, but no matter what you say, the charger will not charge before it's connected to power, and thus it should not matter if you connect charger to wall or prone first.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Aditya Somani try charging by switching off. Try changing the charger or the usb cable of the charger.

Charging via PC takes time and drains faster